# GCP external application to app-engine endpoint authentication

Tags: authentication, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, jwt

We are building a small web-UI using React that will be served up by GCP App-Engine (standard). The UI will display a carousel of images along with some image metadata to our client's employees when they click on a link inside of their internal GIS system. We are looking to authenticate these calls since the App-Engine endpoint will be exposed publicly, and are hoping to use a GCP Service Account private key that will be used by the client to create a time-limited JSON web-token that will give temporary access to the GIS user when they open the web-UI. We are following [this GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication). In summary:

1. We create a new service-account with necessary IAM permissions in GCP along with a key
2. We share the private key with client which they then use to sign a Json Web Token which is passed in the call to our endpoint when user accesses our web-UI from their GIS system
3. Call is authenticated by GCP backend (ESP/OpenAPI)

Question: is this a recommended approach for external system accessing GCP resources or is there a better pattern more applicable to this type of situation (external system accessing GCP resource)?

Comment: Hi, when you talk about endpoints do you suggest you use Google cloud endpoint? Or are you refering to a simple URL hosted on Appengine?

Comment: simple app-engin endpoint although we're open to Cloud Endpoints as well

Comment: Mmmh, reading you I don't spontaneously think to authentication flow like you described. To me it would fit to scenarii where you call an API which backend may be on  Appengine. In the case of a Single Page App, you would rather think to framework like Express (Node), SpringBoot (Java)... In your particular case where it may seems overkill or unfit, have you considered Google IAP? https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs   Using it your premise "since the App-Engine endpoint will be exposed publicly" vanishes.

Comment: @chaiyachaiya: thanks for the IAP ref. Wasn't aware this was an option, however client needs a simpler implementation and I think our initial JWT approach is likely correct for our needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the recommended approach for your use case.

According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication):

[image]

Comment: Thanks - following your ref led us [to this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest) 
 which appears to be perfect for our client's needs. In short a Service Acct private key used to generate JWTs with time limited access.